# Floating or Push Notification for map Navigation in Android 11 & later versions

Tags: android, google-maps, push-notification

I am working on Uber clone. I need to handle the navigation if the driver close the app, how is it possible and best practice to handle the navigation in Android 11 and in latest versions.

I tried to handle with the push notification payload. On the basis of payload, I am handling the user navigation when I get payload through notification I open the required screen.

Comment: If you are trying to create a navigation app using [Google Maps SDKs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk) without using the [NavSDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation), you might want to review their Terms of Service about recreating existing Google products / Features: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/terms#:~:text=Maps%20SDK%20for%20Android%20to%20create%20real%2Dtime%20navigation%20functionality%20substantially%20similar%20to%20the%20functionality%20provided%20by%20the%20Google%20Maps%20for%20Android%20mobile%20app.